# Threads pool, how to properly terminate all threads when there is no more tasks needed to be done?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, threadpool

So far, I set a global variable `taskCompleted` to track how many task has been completed; the `executeTask()` terminates when this reaches to certain number. But the program seems still hang after it completed all submitted task. Why is that ?

```
#define THREAD_NUM 4

typedef struct Task {
    int a, b;
} Task;

Task taskQueue[256];
int taskCount = 0;
int taskCompeleted = 0;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t taskAvailable;

void executeTask(Task* task) {
    //usleep(50000);
    int result = task->a + task->b;
    printf("The sum of %d and %d is %d\n", task->a, task->b, result);
}

void submitTask(Task task) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    taskQueue[taskCount] = task;
    taskCount++;
    pthread_cond_signal(&taskAvailable);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}


void* startThread(void* args) {
    while (1) {
        Task task;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while (taskCount == 0) {
            if (taskCompleted >= 10) {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); 
                return 0;
            }
            pthread_cond_wait(&taskAvailable, &mutex);
        }

        task = taskQueue[0];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < taskCount - 1; i++) {
            taskQueue[i] = taskQueue[i + 1];
        }
        taskCount--;
        taskCompeleted++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        executeTask(&task);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    pthread_t th[THREAD_NUM];
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&taskAvailable, NULL);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < THREAD_NUM; i++) {
        if (pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, &startThread, NULL) != 0) {
            perror("Failed to create the thread");
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Task t = {
            .a = i,
            .b = i
        };
        submitTask(t);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_NUM; i++) {
        if (pthread_join(th[i], NULL) != 0) {
            perror("Failed to join the thread");
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&taskAvailable);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding a variable that the threads can check at the same time as they check if a new task is available:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>

int taskCount = 0;
int taskCompleted = 0;
bool shutdown = false;  // added

void shutdown_queue() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    shutdown = true;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&taskAvailable); // tell all threads to wake up
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

The loop in the thread function would then become (to exit quickly, even if there are tasks left):

```c
void* startThread(void* args) {
    while (true) {
        Task task;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while(!shutdown && taskCount == 0) {           // check for not shutdown
            pthread_cond_wait(&taskAvailable, &mutex);
        }
        if(shutdown) {                                 // if shutdown, bail out
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            return NULL;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

or, to exit only if the task queue is depleted:

```c
void* startThread(void* args) {
    while (true) {
        Task task;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while(taskCount == 0) {           // check for not shutdown
            if(shutdown) {                // if shutdown, bail out
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
                return NULL;
            }
            pthread_cond_wait(&taskAvailable, &mutex);
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can then call `shutdown_queue` to signal all threads to terminate.

Comment: thanks for reply; can you provide the explanation that why my first approach `taskCompleted` counter doesn't successfully terminate the program ?

Comment: @ElleryL You're welcome! You only put 10 tasks in the queue so `taskCompleted >= 100` will always be false. It's also not clear to me how any blocked threads would receive the message that it's time to shutdown in your original solution. If you lower it to `taskCompleted >= 10` it may work, but I think that's just pure "luck".

Comment: I see, `taskCompleted >= 10` condition is set, you saying that there is possibility where, when some thread let's say `th[0]` has been sleeping due to `pthread_cond_wait(&taskAvailable, &mutex)` when `taskCompleted=9` . During its sleep, another thread lets say `th[1]`, also in the sleep. Then a task is added, become available,  `th[1]` requires the lock when the final task available, it proceed and increment `taskCompleted` to `10`. No more tasks now. But `th[0]` is forever sleep. This causes the program to hang

Comment: @ElleryL Yes, it seems like a possibility but I haven't analyzed it in detail. In the version I propose, it's easier to see that it'll work (i.m.o.)

Comment: I notice that you place `taskCompleted++` outside of critical section. Isn't this causing race condition ? Is it efficient to place `shutdown_queue ()`  right after `executeTask(&task);` in the `startThread ` ? I also added a line of condition check `if (taskCompleted >= 10) shutdown = 1` in the `shutdown_queue ()`. In this case, every thread will call this method after it execute a task. But I'm not sure if you have better idea ?

Comment: @ElleryL Yes, sorry, I moved stuff around. It should where the mutex is locked. `shutdown_queue()` would typically be called from the main thread, when it wants to join the threads.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252804/discussion-between-elleryl-and-ted-lyngmo).